# Why is my program's graphics freezing after ~10 seconds?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am unsure why this program appears to stop responding after ~10 seconds. The time displayed will update as the system clock progresses however if I click on the window it will say (not responding). How do I fix this?

```
import turtle as trtl
import datetime as tm
import time

#initialize turtles
clock = trtl.Turtle()
ct = trtl.Turtle()
#variables
running = True

extrazero = "" #adds a zero to the minutes part if less than 10


currenttime = str(tm.datetime.now().hour) + ":" + extrazero + str(tm.datetime.now().minute)
previoustime = ""
#functions
def drawclock():
    ct.ht()
    clock.width(10)
    clock.fd(180)
    clock.lt(90)
    clock.fd(140)
    clock.lt(90)
    clock.forward(320)
    clock.lt(90)
    clock.forward(140)
    clock.lt(90)
    clock.forward(180)
def updateclock():
    global previoustime, currenttime
    ct.clear()
    ct.color('red')
    ct.write(str(currenttime), align = 'center',font = ('alarm clock', 96))
    previoustime = currenttime
#events
drawclock()

while running == True:
    if (tm.datetime.now().minute) < 10: #checks whether or not the zero for minutes is needed
        extrazero = "0"
    else:
        extrazero = ""
    currenttime = str(tm.datetime.now().hour) + ":" + extrazero + str(tm.datetime.now().minute)
    print(currenttime)
    if previoustime != currenttime:
        updateclock()


#keeps screen open
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I run the program, and clicked the screen after 10 seconds, expecting it to simply select the screen, however, it displays that the turtle graphics is not responding.

Comment: it's working fine no freezing. i tested. maybe put some time.sleep() for a better response. tried with minute seconds too and worked fine. you can update your frame using multi thread approach which is not necessary for this but would give you a smoother frames.

Comment: @AminS Odd that you aren't getting the unresponsiveness but I'll take it a as a good sign. I will look into implementing daemon threads into my program. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while running == True:` loop, which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle, is eating up as much time as it can get just to handle an event that happens once a minute.  And potentially blocking other events from firing.  We shouldn't get `time.sleep()` involved and before we get threading involved, let's first rebuild this as a proper turtle program to see if that's sufficient to your need:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from datetime import datetime

DIGIT_FONT = ('alarm clock', 96)

def draw_clock():
    clock.forward(160)
    clock.left(90)
    clock.forward(140)
    clock.left(90)
    clock.forward(320)
    clock.left(90)
    clock.forward(140)
    clock.left(90)
    clock.forward(160)

def update_clock():
    time.clear()
    time.write(current_time, align='center', font=DIGIT_FONT)

def watch_clock():
    global current_time, previous_time

    now = datetime.now()

    extrazero = ""  # add a zero to the minutes part if less than 10

    if now.minute < 10: #checks whether or not the zero for minutes is needed
        extrazero = "0"

    current_time = str(now.hour) + ":" + extrazero + str(now.minute)

    if previous_time != current_time:
        update_clock()
        previous_time = current_time

    screen.ontimer(watch_clock, 1000)  # reexecute this routine one second from now

screen = Screen()

clock = Turtle()
clock.hideturtle()
clock.width(10)
clock.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

time = Turtle()
time.hideturtle()
time.color('red')

running = True

current_time = ""
previous_time = ""

draw_clock()
watch_clock()

screen.mainloop()
```

In your original program, this comment isn't valid:

```
#keeps screen open
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

as these statements are never reached!